# 301 redirect with htaccess & textpattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, textpattern

Trying to set up a 301 redirect for a change in domain. I'm using Textpattern which already has a mod rewrite. When adding the redirect I'm prompted with a error page on the site, stating that the page has resulted in too many redirects!

This is the htaccess file in use...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /relative/web/path/

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] #(this has been added to the default textpattern htaccess file)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks for any advise you can give.

Answer (score 0):

From what domain you try to redirect? May be you have set cycling - trying to redirect from site.com to site.com?

Answer (score 0):

Add this after RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www.yournewdomain.com$).*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yournewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```